# Access the http_images_path constant in a SASS file

Tags: variables, constants, sass

I'm trying to write a @mixin for High Density Display like the iPhone 4+ Retina Display. Therefore I want to automatically append `"@2x"` as a suffix to the images filenames.

Since `image-url()` throws back the whole path I can't append the suffix. Not I'm trying to access the Image-Path I've set in the config to patch the URL together by myself.

Like:

```
   background: $color url("#{$http_images_path}"+"#{$image-name}"+"@2x"+"#{$image-extension}") $x $y no-repeat
```

But #{$http_images_path} is undefined. Is there a way to access it? I don't really want to define the image-path seperatly since it would make the config quite unnecessary.

Even nicer would be if I could split the return of image-url() before the "." of the extension and add "@2x", because I wouldn't need to define the extension separately. I've tried to use Ruby in the sass file like `puts "test"` but it didn't work. So I'm not sure if theres a way to split strings with sass.

Do you guys have some good ideas?

Thanks!
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concatenate your image name inside `image_url()`

config.rb

```
images_dir = "images"
http_images_path = "/your/path"
```

screen.sass

```
$image-name: "asset"
$image-extension: ".png"

.class
  background-image: image_url($image-name + "@2x" + $image-extension)
```

screen.css

```
/* line 4, ../sass/screen.sass */
.class {
  background-image: url('/your/path/asset@2x.png?1327210853');
}
```

If you want to go the route of splitting the file name and inserting `@2x`, you'll have to create an extension where ruby does that for you. You could use [my Compass extension](https://github.com/maxbeatty/goldentype) as a starting point.

Comment: That's pretty close to my current workaround. Thanks for that. And thanks for approving that the only way to split the file name is an extension. Cause I wasn't sure if there is probably a way to use Ruby directly in .sass-files.